# Validação de campo YiiFramework

Tags: yii

Estou iniciando em Yii Framework. Criei a seguinte base de dados:
**Tabela Contato:** codigo, nome, endereço, cidade, bairro, estado;
**Tabela Telefone:** codigo, telefone, idcontato.

Ao clicar em salvar, ele faz a validação apenas nos campos da tabela contato, como faria para ele exibir a mensagem de erro no campo telefone?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente o seu model não esta validando o campo de telefone.

Verifique se no método `rules()` do seu model existe a regra de validação para o campo de telefone.
Seria algo parecido com isso:

```
array('telefone', 'required'),
```

Assim ele será validado como obrigatório.

Neste link tem a lista dos validadores padrões do Yii:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/

Comment: Ótimo, resolveu, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar um array de modelos para serem exibidos os erros, por exemplo

```
$form->errorSummary(array($modelContato, $modelTelefone));
```